# Add an appsetting conditionally in an ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

This question requires both the **key and value** of an appsetting to be conditional. [Set an appsetting value conditionally in an ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678109/set-an-appsetting-value-conditionally-in-an-arm-template) is a related question that requires only a conditional **value**.

We have four parameters.environment.json files. For instance, this is the content of parameters.dev.json.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01...",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env": {
            "value": "dev"
        }
    }
}
```

The requirement is to add an `API_KEY` setting only in the `dev` environment and to have no such key or value in the `ci`, `qa`, and `prod` environments. Something like this comes to mind but of course does not work in an ARM template.

```
"appSettings": [
    {
        [if(parameters('env') eq 'dev')]
        {
            "name": "API_KEY", 
            "value": "[parameters('apikey')]"
        }    
        [endif()]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

So, same approach, but pass in objects ;) If you need you can create another level of indirection (if you need to have more conditions).

```
"variables": {
"Appsettings1": {
    "name": "API_KEY1", 
    "value": "[parameters('apikey1')]",
    "existingsetting": "bla-bla"
},
"Appsettings2": {
    "name": "API_KEY2", 
    "value": "[parameters('apikey2')]",
    "existingsetting": "bla-bla"
},
"realAppsettings": "[variables(parameters('realAppsettings'))]" # < this pulls 
                  # Appsettings1 or Appsettings2 depending on the value or parameter
...
"appSettings": "[variables('realAppsettings')]"
```

Reference: [Set an appsetting value conditionally in an ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678109/set-an-appsetting-value-conditionally-in-an-arm-template)

Comment: How will the variable app setting interact with existing app settings that are already listed in the `appsettings` section? E.g. if we start with `"appSettings": "[ { "EXISTING_SETTING": "some_value" } ]"` then how do we add on the variable?

Comment: I don't think you can combine those, you would need to include the "existing" setting into each `appsettings` variable, I'll update the answer @ShaunLuttin

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... it might lead to significant bloat in the variables, because we will need to duplicate all of our other app settings there. I.e. In your answer, you have repeated only one existing setting. If we have lets say 50 other shared settings, we will need to repeat them all.

Comment: well, i think I might have a workaround for you, but that depends.

Comment: Sure. The answer that I made to the previous question shows the bloat that is starting to happen from all this copying of shared values. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42679274/1108891

Comment: just do you don't get the wrong impression, I'm not going to edit this answer to include it, because that's a completely different question :) also, it is rather huge :) @ShaunLuttin